# Is it possible to stretch a window over multiple displays? And if so, how?

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, multiple-desktops

I use certain programs that have multiple segments in their windows (overleaf, android studio, etc.) and most of those allow you to decompose them into multiple windows, so as to use them over multiple displays (I have 2). However this always takes a bit of time to set up.

My question therefore is: Is it possible to have a **single** window stretch from the **rightmost edge** of the right monitor to the **leftmost edge** of the left monitor, essentially covering 2 screens? Also: how would the virtual desktop function affect this?

I've searched on the interwebs and either nobody has asked this OR the question is stupid (entirely possible) OR I'm bad at research (also entirely possible).

Thanks in advance for any help,
--Ciarán

Comment: I can't help with GNOME, however it's easily possible in other desktops (you just drag it where you want), also not an issue with virtual desktops as most desktops swap both monitors at the same time (unless you change that setting to leave one as is default in GNOME).  If you don't get what you want with GNOME, other DEs offer it.

Comment: So you think I might have to move away from GNOME to get this?

Comment: Oh ok gotcha :) Thanks!